# Linux GUI Find and Replace string within files in directory and sub directories no regex

Tags: linux, gui

I need a GUI find and replace string within files in directory and sub directories for Linux.  **NO REGULAR EXPRESSION.**

Here would be an example of what I need:

```
find /media/directory -type f -exec sed -i -e 's#/mnt/#/media/replacestring/#g' {} \;
```

I need the above except it needs to be GUI.

Answer (score 3):

So I found an answer to the question, but if anyone has a better answer please post.

There is a program called [Regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) (ironic right?), it allows you to do a normal find and replace.  [image]

1. Make sure **recursive** is checked, hit 'Find Files'.
2. Type what you want in the **Search** and **Replace**, hit 'Find'.
3. Check '/g'.
4. The bottom 3 buttons will light up, click on **'All Files'** to replace all.